# Sequelize Как вызвать scope внутри другого scope?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Собственно сам вопрос - как в описании scope для одной модели вызвать scope из другой модели?

У меня есть такой скоуп:

```
includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { studentId: userId },
                    { tutorId: userId },
                ],
            }
        },
    ],
}),
```

Мне необходимо внутри него вызвать следующий скоуп из другой модели:

```
includeStudentAndTutor: () => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'tutor',
        },
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'student',
        }
    ]
}),
```

Так, чтобы в результате это было аналогично тому, как если бы у меня просто был один скоуп со вложенным инклюдом:

```
includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { studentId: userId },
                    { tutorId: userId },
                ],
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'tutor',
                },
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'student',
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачу в итоге решил.

Данный скоуп остается без изменения

```
includeStudentAndTutor: () => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'tutor',
        },
        {
            model: sequelize.model('User'),
            as: 'student',
        }
    ]
}),
```

Обратите внимание, что он описан для модели `BookingSession`

Наш второй скоуп, внутри которого будет вызываться `includeStudentAndTutor`  описан в модели `Conversations` и вот его рабочее описание

```
                includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
                            where: {
                                [Op.or]: [
                                    { studentId: userId },
                                    { tutorId: userId },
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                        sequelize.model('BookingSession').scope('includeStudentAndTutor'),
                    ],
                }),
```

которое возвращает результат аналогичный тому, как если бы этот скоуп не использовал скоуп `includeStudentAndTutor`, а был бы просто описан таким образом:

```
includeBookingSessionAndUsers: (userId) => ({
    include: [
        {
            model: sequelize.model('BookingSession'),
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [
                    { studentId: userId },
                    { tutorId: userId },
                ],
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'tutor',
                },
                {
                    model: sequelize.model('User'),
                    as: 'student',
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
})
```